# Convert array of strings to a StrongParameters whitelist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a string of field names like this `"name,address.postal_code"` that acts as a whitelist for a hash that looks like this:

```rb
{
  name: "Test",
  email: "test@test.com",
  address:  {
    postal_code: "12345",
    street: "Teststreet"
  }
}
```

So now what I want to to is convert the whitelist string into a format that is accepted by `ActionController::Parameters.permit`: `[:name, address: [:postal_code]]`

What would be the best way to do this? I've tried `group_by` and some other things but it always turned out way more complicated that I think it needs to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses `Array#group_by` to parse the nested keys recursively:

```
module WhitelistParser
  # Parses a comma delimed string into an array that can be passed as arguments
  # to the rails params whitelist
  def self.parse(string)
    ary = string.split(',').map do |key|
      if key.include?('.')
        key.split('.').map(&:intern)
      else
        key.intern
      end
    end
    make_argument_list(ary)
  end

  private

  def self.make_argument_list(ary)
    nested, flat = ary.partition { |a| a.is_a?(Array) }
    if flat.any?
      flat.tap do |a|
        a.push(make_hash(nested)) if nested.any?
      end
    elsif nested.any?
      make_hash(nested)
    end
  end

  def self.make_hash(nested)
    nested.group_by(&:first).transform_values do |value|
      make_argument_list(value.map { |f, *r| r.length > 1 ? r : r.first  })
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
irb(main):004:0> params = ActionController::Parameters.new(foo: { a: 1, b: 2, bar: { baz: 3} })
irb(main):005:0> whitelist = WhitelistParser.parse('a,b,bar.baz')
irb(main):006:0> params.require(:foo).permit(*whitelist)
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "bar"=><ActionController::Parameters {"baz"=>3} permitted: true>} permitted: true>
```

Spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe WhitelistParser do
  describe ".parse" do
    let(:string) { "name,address.postal_code,foo.bar,foo.bar.baz" }
    it "handles flat arguments" do
      expect(WhitelistParser.parse(string)).to include :name
    end
    it "handles hash arguments" do
      expect(WhitelistParser.parse(string).last).to include(
        { address: [:postal_code] }
      )
    end
    it "handles nested hash arguments" do
      expect(WhitelistParser.parse(string).last[:foo]).to include(
        { bar: [:baz] }
      )
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal, but it should work:

```ruby
def to_strong_parameters_compatible(fields)
  fields # fields="name,address.postal_code,address.street"
    .split(',') # ["name", "address.postal_code", "address.street"]
    .group_by { |val| val.split('.').first } # { "name" => ["name"], "address" => ["address.postal_code", "address.street"]}
    .inject([]) do |params, hash|
      k = hash.first
      v = hash.last
      puts "k: #{k}"
      puts "v: #{v}"
      # 1st: k="name", v=["name"]
      # 2nd: k="address", v=["address.postal_code", "address.street"]

      if v.length == 1
        params << k
        # 1st: params=["name"]
      else
        params << { k => v.map { |chain| chain.split('.').last } }
        # 2nd: params=["name", { "address" => ["postal_code", "street"]}]
      end

      params
    end
end

fields = "name,address.postal_code,address.street"

# How you should use it:
params.permit(*to_strong_parameters_compatible(fields))
```

Note: it won't work for fields like `a.b.c`... you would have to make this algo recursive (it should not be hard)

**EDIT:** and here is the recursive version

```ruby
def to_strong_parameters_compatible(fields)
  fields
    .split(',')
    .group_by { |val| val.split('.').first }
    .inject([]) do |params, hash|
      k = hash.first
      v = hash.last

      if v.length == 1
        params << k
      else
        params << {
          k => to_strong_parameters_compatible(
            v
              .map { |chain| chain.split('.').drop(1).join('.') }
              .join(',')
          )
        }
      end

      params
    end
end
fields = "name,address.postal_code,address.street,address.country.code,address.country.name"
to_strong_parameters_compatible(fields)
# ["name", {"address"=>["postal_code", "street", {"country"=>["code", "name"]}]}]

# How you should use it:
params.permit(*to_strong_parameters_compatible(fields))
```